# Why is .Top, .Left and bounds appearing in an error message "not a member of a system array"

Tags: vb.net

Please can you help me? 
I have the code below and its causing the following error when it intersects with the food.bounds.

bounds is not a member of system array

Thank you in advance.

```
Dim snake(1000) As PictureBox
Public food(1000) As PictureBox
Dim length As Integer = -1
Dim lefttoright As Integer = 0
Dim uptodown As Integer = 0
Dim random As New Random

If snake(0).Bounds.IntersectsWith(food.Bounds) Then
        snake_body()
        food.Top = random.Next(pb_field.Top, pb_field.Bottom - 10)
        food.Left = random.Next(pb_field.Left, pb_field.Right - 10)

Private Sub snake_body()
    length += 1
    snake(length) = New PictureBox
    With snake(length)
        .Height = 10
        .Width = 10
        .BackColor = Color.Red
        .Top = snake(length - 1).Top
        .Left = snake(length - 1).Left + 10
    End With
    Me.Controls.Add(snake(length))
    snake(length).BringToFront()

End Sub
```

Comment: Please post your full stacktrace. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure how to get to the stacktrace?

Comment: `food` is an array. `food(0)` would be a PictureBox, as long as you had set `food(0) = New PictureBox` somwhere previously.

Comment: Do you have a error-handling? Try-Catch? You can catch the exception and output ex.ToString. Then you have the stacktrace.

Comment: @etalon11 : It's a compiler error, not a runtime error. His program won't even run. The trouble being he calls `food.Left` instead of `food(<index here>).Left`.

Comment: @VisualVincent yeah sure. your right. I have to get used to the fact that users post compiler errors and not always exceptions...